# Which Microcontroller to use

Tags: shields, wifi, lcd, sd-card

I want to use a wifi shield, as well as a 2.8 inch touch LCD shield; both would fit the arduino uno V3 nicely.  Is that the best microcontroller to use

Comment: That isn't a mocrocontroller, it's a development platform.

Comment: Without any further comments on what you **intend** to do with it, it is impossible to say what is "the best" for your situation. Please provide more details about your project.

Comment: There are Uno Wifi shields and there are Uno LCD shields; do you ask whether you can stack both of them on top of the Uno simultaneously ?

Comment: yes, can I stack them simultaneously. @Omer

Comment: I meant which arduino microcontroller would be best to use? @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Comment: I want to be able to scan for existing networks, and then go from there. @ jfpoilpret

Comment: I was wondering if the mega 2560 would work better? @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Comment: @BMode35 - The main difference with the mega is that it has more pins for input and output. So you can control more external motors, switches etc.

Comment: If you want to do wifi and a GUI, you probably shouldn't be using an Arduino (or at least not an ATmega-based one) at all.  Get something with more memory - it won't cost more, in fact it will probably cost less.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, regarding stacking a WiFi Arduino Shield on top of a LCD Shield:

> can I stack them simultaneously

The obvious answer is - **it depends on the shields**. Each shield might use a different set of Arduino I/O pins, making them unavailable to the next shield stacked on top of it.

for example, this [formal Arduino WiFi shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWiFiShield) makes **I/O pins 10, 11, 12, 13 and 7** (on Arduino Uno) unavailable to the next top shield.

Unfortunately, this [LCD KeyPad shield](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/LCD_KeyPad_Shield_For_Arduino_SKU:_DFR0009) needs pins 7 and 10 available (among others) in order to function properly. This makes it incompatible for stacking on top of the WiFi shield mentioned above (or vice versa).

It doesn't mean that there is no way that **any** LCD shield could be stacked on top of a WiFi shield, but to be honest, I couldn't easily find any LCD shield that won't collide with a WiFI shield pins. You might want to change approach and send the WiFi data using the built-in Serial to a computer.

> Is that the best microcontroller to use

If there would have been a manifest to this website, I'm sure that "The best product is the one that meet your needs best" would be it's first sentence. In order for someone with experience to answer what is best, (s)he would need to know your exact needs. Since you are still not sure what they are, and just want to play around a bit, I imagine that the classic Arduino Uno R3 could help you find your way, especially if you are doing your first steps with Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to chime in with the others and say "It depends." The Uno, or more precisely its Atmega328p microcontroller, is rather memory limited, especially the RAM memory needed for data buffers, stack-frames, and tables such as the character-generator for the LCD. That last one can usually be kept in program memory, but note that if you're having to plan memory assignment before you even start the project, it's a pretty good sign that you should consider something more capable.

An Arduino Mega 2560 is about twice the price of the Uno (in the US, US$50 vs. US$25) but gives you 4 times the RAM memory, 8 times the flash (program) memory, and a bunch more (sorry to get all technical :) I/O pins. Of these, the RAM is likely to be your most stringent limit with the UNO.

I keep one Arduino Mega around for prototyping or when don't want to build another board for an experiment, and a handful of AtMega328p chips to build into "Arduin-ettes" for my more permanent gadgets. Most of my toys will fit on the '328 chip but it's awfully nice to be able to shove a ton of code, libraries, debugging statements, logging buffers and what have you, into the larger processor without having to think about what will fit. Or, what's worse, if I cause a stack crash by stuffing all of that into too-little memory, I could waste a lot of time debugging a presumed coding error when it was really an out-of-memory problem.